# Contribution receipt has "display in honor roll" when personal campaign pages is off

Tags: drupal, civicontribute

After upgrading the CiviCRM to version 4.7.15 on Drupal Commons 7.50, I noticed that CiviContribute receipts are coming in with a field "Personal Campaign Page: Display in Honor Roll", however, personal campaign pages are turned off. Is this a bug or do I need to adjust my settings somewhere? See screenshots below.

**From Receipt**
[image]

**From CiviContribute Page settings**
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Christia, how well does CiviCRM work on Drupal Commons Install?  We need a community on our site and have been looking at CiviCRM/Drupal Commons and WordPress/CiviCRM/BuddyPress.  Any feed back and maybe a link to your website would be appreciated.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't care for commons much and it was harder to maintain CRM and anything else that doesn't come with it. I really like it with a Drupal 7 standard/custom build. Commons is so heavy and so is CRM. I think Organic Groups is more flexible for building a community anyway. Our website is FosterClub.com and I completely rebuilt it from scratch since I had posted this. All in all, the CiviCRM backend is going to work the same way but integrating into the rest is much easier without commons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though Personal Campaign Pages was off, Widgets had become enabled. Once I disabled Widgets, this went away from the donation receipt.